# Spring scope prototype

Tags: spring, annotations, prototype

I need a new instance for the class Wrapper, each time wrapper() is invoked.

```
 @Configuration
class Conf{
 @Bean
 A mybean(){
   return new A();
 }

 @Bean
 @Scope("prototype")
 Wrapper wrapper(){
    return new Wrapper(mybean());
 }

 @Bean
 C cbean(){
    return new C(wrapper);
 }
 @Bean
 D dbean(){
    return new D(wrapper);
 }
}
```

The beans, C and D thus created should have different instances of Wrapper. I don't think the above is going to work even if it is @Configuration.
Alternately, I can use lookup method, but I am not sure even Spring 4.0 supports it yet.
I can use javax.inject.Provider as well, but that is going to create more clutter.

Comment: Have you tried? Because that code above works for me.

Comment: If you have some other code in your application, I think you need to post that for investigation. The code above, as @StéphaneNicoll said, doesn't have any issues.

Comment: Yes, it works as expected, I didn't try before posting.